# how can i reinstall the image viewer for ubuntu 22.04.3?

Tags: reinstall

I had trouble with image viewer locking up and uninstalled it, thinking i could reinstall from Ubuntu software (the orange briefcase).  It is not on the list of image viewers.  How can i get it back?

Answer (score 1):

To reinstall the default image viewer for Ubuntu 22.04 run the following command:

```
sudo apt install eog
```

eog or the Eye of GNOME is a simple graphics viewer for the GNOME  desktop environment.